# expo issue with ubuntu can't run expo start

Tags: react-native, ubuntu

i run an application React Naive with Expo, i'm using ubuntu operation system .
i did clone the project repo then run the command yarn install then i want run the project on the Expo go on my phone i run expo start the error below

```
expo start

Command 'expo' not found, did you mean:

  command 'expr' from deb coreutils (8.30-3ubuntu2)
  command 'expn' from deb sendmail-base (8.15.2-18)

Try: sudo apt install <deb name>
```

i have install node , watchman , Expocli

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't install expo-cli module globally.

Use this command for install expo-cli module.

```
npm i expo-cli -g
```

You can reference these URLs.

[installing node module globally](https://%20https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-packages-globally)

[installing expo-cli](https://docs.expo.dev/get-started/installation/)

Comment: did i have to run the command same path of the project?

Comment: No. You can use this command on any path.

Comment: it still not working

Comment: please let me know your gmail addr.